# Illustrator gradients along (not following) a shape/curve?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

How could I add gradients along an object/path (not following the path, but using it as a base, like inner glow) ?

Sample:

[image: Sample image]

Comment: What is it that you want, that inner glow doesn't do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Illustrator CS6, simply apply a gradient to the stroke and choose the Across stroke option in the gradient panel.

[image: Gradient]

For earlier versions of Illustrator a blend may work better.

Draw two paths. 
Stroke one with the background color and one with the highlight color. (I used magenta so you can see the path.)

 Select both paths.

Choose `Object > Blend > Make` from the menu.

[image: blend]

The Blend method works in CS6 as well, but the gradients on strokes make it a bit easier in CS6.